Minimum money to use $1084$ batteries if price of each battery is $\$1$, and customers get a free one by returning three empty batteries to the store.

A battery store has a special offer for customers. Customers get a new battery for free by returning all three empty (used) batteries to the store. If the price of one battery is \$$1$, what is the minimum amount of money do we need to be able to use $1084$ batteries?
$1)\$723\qquad\quad 2)\$729\qquad\quad3)\$810\qquad\quad4)\$813\qquad\quad5)\$1084$

I could solve this problem with some estimations and testing the available options:
Let's say we start with $k$ batteries, we roughly can use $k+\dfrac k3+\dfrac k9+\dfrac{k}{27}+\dfrac k{81}$ batteries by returning each three of them to store. So,
$$\dfrac {121}{81}k=1084\Rightarrow \dfrac{120}{80}k\approx 1084\Rightarrow k\approx722$$
So it makes sense to start testing the first option:
$$723+241+80+26+8+2=1080$$
But through divisions, $1+2+2+2+2$ remains unused which we can buy $3$ new batteries and then another battery from them. Hence, we arrive at the desired number of batteries: $1080+3+1=1084$. Consequently, the first option is the correct.

I think the problem would be more interesting if the options were not given. I'm wondering how we can solve this problem systematically without estimations/try and error. I believe the equation will be:
$$k+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^3}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^4}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^5}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^6}\rfloor+\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^7}\rfloor+m=1084$$
where $m$ accounts for the number of extra batteries we can get from using remainders of the divisions. However, I'm not sure how to continue further.

There is dependency on when you need the batteries. If you need them all immediately, you have to suck it up and buy all $1084$ batteries up front. (You will have to redeem your bonus batteries later.)
On the other hand, if timing isn't an issue:
Buy and use three batteries.
Trade three used for one new battery; and buy two more. Use these three batteries.
Trade three used for one new battery; and buy two more. Use these three batteries.
Etc.
So, after the initial purchase of three batteries, you subsequently get $3$ for the price of $2$.
Thus, after the initial purchase of $3$ batteries, if you subsequently get $3$ batteries for the price of $2$ batteries $360$ times, you will have gotten $1083$ batteries. But also you will end up with three used batteries, which you can trade for a free battery (your $1084$th battery!). So, altogether you buy (i.e., pay for) $3+2\cdot 360=723$ batteries.
Of course, once you've worked all this out, you can just buy the $723$ batteries up front so as to have less trips to the store.

I think it is unrealistic to solve this without estimation and trial, but you can do very close estimation to reduce the trials.  If you know that the sum of the geometric series $1+\frac 13+\frac 19 + \ldots =\frac 32$ you know that the answer will be about $\frac 23 \cdot 1084=722 \frac 23$ and cannot be less.  That makes it natural to start at $723$, which works here.  If the first try doesn't work, you expect that adding one battery bought will add about $\frac 32$ batteries used, so you can next try adding $\frac 23$ of the shortfall in batteries used.
When you compute the number of batteries you can use you need to carry the remaining number of empties down to the next level.  Your numerator for the $\frac k9$ term should be $k+ k \pmod 3$ to include the empties that you couldn't use last time and so on.

If you start with $k$ batteries, then you will have used up at least:
$$L = k + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^3}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{3^4}\right\rfloor + \dots$$
batteries. Note that this is an infinite sum, and it does not affect this solution's process because at one point, there will exist some $p \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $3^p > k$, so the remaining floors will simply evaluate to $0$. Moreover, this allows us to utilize the infinite geometric series formula because:
$$L < k + \dfrac{k}{3} + \dfrac{k}{3^2} + \dfrac{k}{3^3} + \dots \equiv \dfrac{3k}{2}$$
Solving for $3k/2 = 1084$ gives $k = 722.\dot 6$. Since $L ≤ 1084$, we can use values of $k$ around $722$ as our focus of investigation.
If $k = 722$, then after the battery returning/offer process, we will have used up: $$722 + 240 + 80 + 27 + 9 + 3 + 1 = 1082\text{ batteries}$$
upon paying $\$722$.
Taking this one step up, paying $\$723$ for an initial of $k = 723$ means the usage of:
$$723 + 241 + 80 + 27 + 9 + 3 + 1 = 1084\text{ batteries}$$
Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{\$723}$.
